# How do i queue push notification message if user is offline and push when they are back online?

Tags: javascript

I  build a push notification service using javascripts everything seems fine and working as it should but only one problem, if i push a message when a user is offline the message never get delivered if the user is back online my code below;
seviceWorker.js

```
'use strict';

const pushData = event.data.text();
console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);
var data = JSON.parse(pushData);
const title = 'Test';
const options = {
  body: 'This is a test',
  icon: 'logo.png',
  badge: 'logo.png',
  sound:'juntos-607.mp3',
  image:data.image,
  vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 400],
  requireInteraction: true
};

event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
  // Handle click event
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click received.');

event.notification.close();

event.waitUntil(
  clients.openWindow('www.test.com')
);
});
});
```

service.js

```
'use strict';

const applicationServerPublicKey = 'some key';

const pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-btn');

let isSubscribed = false;
let swRegistration = null;

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
const base64 = (base64String + padding)
.replace(/\-/g, '+')
.replace(/_/g, '/');

 const rawData = window.atob(base64);
 const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

 for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
 outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
 }
 return outputArray;
 }
 // Checking if serviceworker and pushManager is active
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
console.log('Service Worker and Push are supported');

navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js')
.then(function(swReg) {
console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

swRegistration = swReg;
initializeUI();
})
.catch(function(error) {
console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
});
} else {
console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}

function initializeUI() {
pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
pushButton.disabled = true;
if (isSubscribed) {
  // TODO: Unsubscribe user
  unsubscribeUser();
} else {
  subscribeUser();
}
});
// Set the initial subscription value
swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
.then(function(subscription) {
isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);

if (isSubscribed) {
  console.log('User IS subscribed.');
} else {
  console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
}

updateBtn();
});
}

function updateBtn() {
if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked';
pushButton.disabled = true;
updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
return;
}
if (isSubscribed) {
pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
} else {
pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
}

pushButton.disabled = false;
}



function subscribeUser() {
const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
userVisibleOnly: true,
applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
})
.then(function(subscription) {
console.log('User is subscribed.');

updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

isSubscribed = true;

updateBtn();
})
.catch(function(error) {
console.error('Failed to subscribe the user: ', error);
updateBtn();
});
}

function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
// TODO: Send subscription to application server

const subscriptionJson = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-json');
const subscriptionDetails =
document.querySelector('.js-subscription-details');

if (subscription) {
subscriptionJson.textContent = JSON.stringify(subscription);
subscriptionDetails.classList.remove('is-invisible');

// Send data to database
var datastring = JSON.stringify(subscription)
$.ajax({
  url : "/push-api", // Url of backend (can be python, php, etc..)
  type: "POST", // data type (can be get, post, put, delete)
  data : datastring, // data in json format
  contentType: 'application/json',
  async : false, // enable or disable async (optional, but suggested as false if you need to 
  populate data afterwards)
  success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
  }
  });

  } else {
  subscriptionDetails.classList.add('is-invisible');
  }
  }

  // Get user subcription
  function unsubscribeUser() {
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
  if (subscription) {
  // TODO: Tell application server to delete subscription
   // Send data to database
  var datastring = JSON.stringify(subscription)
  $.ajax({
  url : "/delete-push-api", // Url of backend (can be python, php, etc..)
  type: "POST", // data type (can be get, post, put, delete)
  data : datastring, // data in json format
  contentType: 'application/json',
  async : false, // enable or disable async (optional, but suggested as false if you need to 
  populate data afterwards)
  success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
  }
  });
  return subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  })
 .catch(function(error) {
 console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
 })
 .then(function() {
updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);

console.log('User is unsubscribed.');
isSubscribed = false;

updateBtn();
});
}
```

This was build from documentation from google codelab. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic thing because your code is never working when user is not in your website. To solve this problem, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging services. Firebase FCM is free. FCM is used to push notifications on Mobile Apps and Web. You can find a detailed documentation over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)